# error in openid for java

Tags: java, servlets, openid

I'm using library openid4java in my project.

I have tried to use examples:

http://communitygrids.blogspot.com/2009/12/quick-guide-to-using-googles-openid.html

and

http://crisdev.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/openid4java-login-example/

But always I'm getting next error when I'm trying to login via google or via myopenid:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource  at
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setAttribute(DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.java:128)
>     at
>   org.openid4java.discovery.xrds.XrdsParserImpl.parseXmlInput(XrdsParserImpl.java:169)
>     at
>   org.openid4java.discovery.xrds.XrdsParserImpl.parseXrds(XrdsParserImpl.java:50)
>     at
>   org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.retrieveXrdsLocation(YadisResolver.java:448)
>     at
>   org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:252)
>     at
>   org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:232)
>     at
>   org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:166)
>     at org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:147)
>     at org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:129)
>     at
>   org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager.discover(ConsumerManager.java:542)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsps.consumer_005fredirect_jsp._jspService(consumer_005fredirect_jsp.java:108)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
>     at photoGallery.EnterOpenIdServlet.doGet(EnterOpenIdServlet.java:17)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource  at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
>     at photoGallery.EnterOpenIdServlet.doGet(EnterOpenIdServlet.java:17)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource  at
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setAttribute(DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.java:128)
>     at
>   org.openid4java.discovery.xrds.XrdsParserImpl.parseXmlInput(XrdsParserImpl.java:169)
>     at
>   org.openid4java.discovery.xrds.XrdsParserImpl.parseXrds(XrdsParserImpl.java:50)
>     at
>   org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.retrieveXrdsLocation(YadisResolver.java:448)
>     at
>   org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:252)
>     at
>   org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:232)
>     at
>   org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:166)
>     at org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:147)
>     at org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:129)
>     at
>   org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager.discover(ConsumerManager.java:542)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsps.consumer_005fredirect_jsp._jspService(consumer_005fredirect_jsp.java:108)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     ... 28 more

I'm compiling it under eclipse and running also under eclipse (Run on server option), I'm not deploying war file to tomcat server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my error.
Problem was in using too new additional libraries. For correct work use libraries which is you are downloading with openid4java